# Reputation History from Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, reputation, data-explorer

Is there a way to get the reputation history for a user in [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).  I know you can do this through the [StackExchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) through Reputation Changes. But there's a limit of 10K queries a day (at 100 Reputation Changes a query) so that does not seem very promising. Perhaps I'm wrong but it looks like this falls under Feature Requests.

Comment: Maybe a startpoint could be this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231408/query-for-top-users-rep-over-the-past-n-days/232082#232082

Answer (score 10):

You can't get the exact reputation history because not all information is publicly available in SEDE (like downvotes).

The closest to your question is [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/203302/user-reputation-history?uid=447356#graph).

It shows the reputation gain for the following categories:

- Upvoted question
- Upvoted Answer
- Downvotes on own Posts
- Accepted Answers
- Suggested Edits
- Bounties started
- Bounties Received

resulting, for a particular user whose name remains in Shadows, to this graph:

[image]

Comment: This seems to me a very heavy query on the data explorer.

Comment: Sure, but it works and stays within the time and size limits although I'm known for my torn downs of SEDE as can be seen here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234797/sede-reports-could-not-allocate-a-new-page-for-database-tempdb  I would not claim Nick had to buy new disks because of me but I certainly managed to push it beyond its limits...

Comment: I'm getting time limit.

Comment: Yeah, the query is nasty. It did run before but maybe the move to Denver didn't help in this case. You could try removing one or two subqueries ...

Comment: The received bounties do not seem to work for me anymore. Nevertheless, really impressive query! 

Comment: @KimKern that was a bug, now fixed: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/203302/user-reputation-history?uid=4694994#graph