# Query for top users (rep) over the past n days

Tags: support, reputation, data-explorer

Can someone more familiar with SQL construct a query that shows the top users (rep) over the past n days, similar to how [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week) does it.

Comment: The SEDE doesn't support history as far as I know.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin: It *is* the history!

Comment: @Werner I meant as far as I know you can't view reputation history with a SEDE query but I'm not sure.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin: The requested query should *aggregate* this information from the database; it wouldn't be a look-up of reputation for some period.

Comment: @Werner as in you can only do an average over the entire rep history? So this query, *rep gained over the past n days*, is not supported?

Comment: @Tshepang: No, an aggregation doesn't necessarily refer to an average. It will be fully possible (for someone with the SQL skills).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get the exact numbers from SEDE because its data is only refreshed once a week. Voting is anonymous also in SEDE so you can't retrieve the info on the downvotes casted by users.

I still think [Top users rep per x weeks](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/196452/top-users-rep-per-x-weeks?numofweeks=2&top=10) comes close to what you are looking for.

The query takes 3 steps:

1. It sums the upvotes, downvotes and accepted rep gain per Post (questions and answers) from the votes cast in a period
2. It then sums those grouped by user
3. It outer joins the suggested edits and bounties for a user

The top 10 outcome per May 24th 2014 for a 2 week period based on the dump of May 16th:

```
 User Link      | SumRepPeriod
------------------------------
Arbel           |  10352
Jon Skeet       |   9314
Martijn Pieters |   4375
BalusC          |   4370
Mathew MacLean  |   3862
Darin Dimitrov  |   3699
VonC            |   3621
Gordon Linoff   |   3569
CommonsWare     |   3183
Hans Passant    |   3014
Marc Gravell    |   2791
```

NOTE: this query does not take into consideration the 200 rep/day limit.

Comment: Does this query take the 200 rep/day limit into consideration?

Comment: No, it does not. It would complicate matters immensely...

Comment: And it already is a hectic query. Anyways, that would explain why, for example, John Skeet ranks higher than Martijn Peters, which contrasts with what we see here: http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week.