# Is there any documentation about the data model behind the reputation system?

Tags: discussion, reputation

While I found some good articles about reputation systems in general, and Stack Overflow in particular, I didn't find any article about the data model used.

I know the data is stored in a MS-SQL database so it is some kind of relational model.

I am especially interested how the reputation points are stored (by user, by entity that has the points, in both). 
In my opinion the reputation is like a currency and you could implement it like real bookkeeping (with transactions and consistent sums on creditors and debtors). But is it implemented this way?

Comment: Thanks - i think this is worth an "answer". are there any checks between the redundant values? could they differ in any way? does this matter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The exact database schema is not known but we can get a glimpse of it by looking at what is available in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). The data dictionary is described in [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) and I've used that combined with the information schema info to create an [ERD](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250396/database-diagram-of-stack-exchange-model/250439#250439).

If you look at those tables you'll see that the `users` table has an attribute `reputation`. That field is a redundant value, stored there for performance reasons.

To calculate the reputation you'll have to look at the votes and certain actions. The votes (up/down/accept) are stored in the `votes` table, a row for each vote indicated with the votetypeid (up=2, down=3, accept=1 etc). Each type of vote carries its own reputation. Approved suggested edits also gives reputation, those are found in `suggestededits` if you filter on `ApprovalDate` is not null.

If you bring all that data together you can create an graph of your reputation over time as I [show in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234414/158100). That is what you would call *the transactions*

On any site you can [audit your reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/reputation). Back in the days that page also had a re-calc button which you could click if there was for some reason a discrepancy between the reputation in your profile and what you should have based on your posts.
You'll find questions on that topic in the tag [reputation-recalc](/questions/tagged/reputation-recalc).

Today if there is a difference we blame [caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221414/158100).

Comment: thanks for this really in depth answer. Its much more than i expected :-)

Comment: one little question remains: how are downvotes represented in data base? As a special type?

Comment: Down votes are in the Votes table, votetypeid = 3 (downmod)