# Why isn't the summation of a user's score equal to their reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, data-explorer, data-dump

I was going over the [database schema documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678) and was trying to understand how the Post scoring system works. I was expecting this query:

```
select sum(p.score)
from posts p
where p.OwnerUserId = 766570;
// returns 2130 (what is this?)
```

where I simply sum the scores of the posts made by [me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766570/abbood) to be the same as my reputation

```
select u.reputation
from users u
where u.id = 766570;
// returns 22769 (correct)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Remember that downvotes deduct a whole lot less rep than upvotes, but count the same in score totals.

Comment: The *score* is the total of upvotes - downvotes. So a post with score of 8 might be +11 / - 3. This in turn is 11 * 10 - 3 * 2 = 104 reputation. Note that also reputation cannot go below zero so if the first post of a user got three downvotes first they'd be at 1 rep, and receiving an upvote brings them to 11 even though the post is +1 / -3. But that's an edge case and doesn't greatly affect reputation calculations. Also, that's just vote calculations. Accepts also grant 15 rep and approved suggested edits add 2 each.

Comment: Just the sum of scores omits many things (bounties, CW-posts, daily reputation cup, etc.) You can have a look at the SEDE query provided here: [Reputation History from Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144716). Some time ago I tried to create a query [related to this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1561696/comparison-of-actual-reputation-and-estimated-reputation-from-votes). I did it based on a conversation [in the SEDE chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1223/2022/2/23).

Comment: Also don't forget about bounties (both earned and deducted), and votes that don't count toward reputation due to hitting the rep cap.

Comment: @VLAZ: There is also the daily reputation points cap (of 200?).