# Save vote/visit stats of all questions and answers to a file so that one can show one's stats over time, not just the points?

Tags: feature-request, statistics, views, database, community-data

*Since this feature request was answered with a good workaround, I am rather asking here for any tool to get the stats of the votes and visits of questions and the votes of the answers as a file.*

Old heading was:

> Since view statistics are not stored: Button "Save time series of the views of all questions to a user file". And: "Upload file for stats" on SE site

Old question was:

The number of views is not stored, that is why the users cannot get a chart or overview over time from Stack Exchange. Still: If storing is the problem, why not giving the users themselves the chance to store the views per question on their local drive or in an online "dropbox"?

Of course, everyone can just look up their most important questions and create an Excel sheet or print out a pdf of the question once in a while to have a history of its number of views, but that is manual work.

I suggest an export button that lets you manually export all of your queries together with their views and other information at the current timestamp into a json file or thelike on your local hard disk or into a "dropbox", at best updating the same existing file again and again so that you can extract data over time from just one file.

And in addition one might consider an option in the profile to do this automatically: store the csv after a certain time starting as soon as you visit the site, perhaps the file can also be saved online in a kind of dropbox so that it is not dependent on the computer you are working on. The highest possible storing frequency would be to update the file whenever you access a SO site, the lowest would be to store this once per quarter (or never).

This feature would meet a lot of interest, see the many earlier feature requests:

- [Stack Exchange Community Statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89909/stack-exchange-community-statistics/90817#90817)
- [Is there a possibility of seeing a graph of a question's views over time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92554/is-there-a-possibility-of-seeing-a-graph-of-a-questions-views-over-time)
- [Is there any analytics information that moderators can access for individual questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/is-there-any-analytics-information-that-moderators-can-access-for-individual-que)
- [Statistic for views over time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230711/statistic-for-views-over-time) --> Only workaround to take the votes timeline

As a bonus to this feature-request, on Stack Exchange, there should be a feature that can load that local file and show the graphs and statistics for all questions saved locally in that file.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89909/stack-exchange-community-statistics/353886#353886 for a renewed request of a global storage of the views in the SE database instead. In 2020, this might be possible. Then, this question here would be unneeded.

Comment: I have a SEDE query like that and I'm [archiving it regularly](https://web.archive.org/web/20200830210324/https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/740847/networkwide-questions-per-account-ordered-by-view-count?AccountId=6085540).

Comment: @Glorfindel Respect, I see you have access to the SE database then and you can ask for the stats of your user. Could you not suggest this option as a new feature to reach the aim of this question - to export your final SELECT query to a user file with a menu button? It is actually almost the feature in question that you provide! And if that is possible, why not doing this on a global scale anyway??? Which would mean that https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89909/stack-exchange-community-statistics/353886#353886 could be put into practice?

Comment: The [views for a question is data that's available from the SE API](//api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question). For example, [here are the view counts for all of your Stack Overflow questions](//api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-on-users#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=11154841&filter=!--Tafs5GeTGy&site=stackoverflow&run=true) ([direct API call](//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/11154841/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!--Tafs5GeTGy)). You could create a program/script, or even just a `curl` call, which saves this data on your local machine whenever you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a [Stack Exchange Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/740847/networkwide-questions-per-account-ordered-by-view-count) which you can run to generate a list of your questions across the network, including statistics like the number of views. It needs your network account ID, which you can find by navigating to https://stackexchange.com/users/current – you'll find the number in the URL of the page you'll end up on. SEDE has a built-in functionality to export the results as CSV, so you can keep an archive yourself, or save the page in the Wayback Machine (the latter only works if you provide the AccountId parameter in the URL, so https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/740847/networkwide-questions-per-account-ordered-by-view-count?AccountId=6085540).

[image]

Please note that SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning.

Comment: @Lorenz Doing this all manually with the existing tools we have is the best you're going to get. We are not going to invest time building extremely complicated features that only a tiny number of people would ever find useful, especially when those users can already do mostly the same thing with SEDE.

Comment: Shortcut to get the user ID in the URL: [middle-click](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357554/how-to-get-a-bigger-reputation-graph/399935#399935) on the mouse on the badge symbol in the upper right menu.

Comment: This query does not work anymore, it seems: `Line 1: Invalid object name 'Data.StackExchangePOC.dbo.Posts'.`

Comment: @questionto42 thanks for the comment, [you've found a bug in the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396849/295232).